# Remove duplicated values from double array in Java?

Tags: java, android, duplicates, double

I have a double array:

```
double []signs = new double [sizelines];
```

I need to remove all the duplicated values or simply extract the values without duplication.

I tried to use `Set` and `HashSet` but I couldn't make it work with a double. I used the following code:

```
  Double[] Duplicates(double[] signs) {

       Set<double[]> myset = new HashSet<double[]>(Arrays.asList(signs));
        Double[] signsfinal = myset.toArray(new Double[myset.size()]);

       return signsfinal;
    }
```

and I received the following error:

source[0] of type double[] cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.Double[]

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Can you provide some code?

Comment: You need to be more precise. What do you mean by "remove"? Post example of input, expected output and code you tried so far.

Comment: "I couldn't make it work" is not enough information for anyone to know what's wrong with your code.  You need to [edit] your question to include to code and any compile/runtime errors you're getting.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: Can you set `signs` to `Double[]` array? This would allow you to use collections like Set without problems.

Comment: Also you need to clarify what you mean by "remove". Lets say that you have array of `{1, 2, 1}`. Do you want to remove both duplicates and get only `{2}`, or remove all duplicates except one like `{1, 2}` (or should it be maybe `{2, 1}`)?

Comment: I meant extracting all the existing values without any duplication. So if my array contains {1,2,1} I want obtain {1,2}

Answer (score 1):

The Set and HashSet classes don't work with primitive types like `double` or `int`, you have to do something like this : `Set<Double> mySet = new HashSet<Double>();` and then add elements like this : `mySet.add(new Double(12.5));`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a Set from your array. You need only to define `myArray` of type `Double[]` to not have the error mentioned by Pshemo in the comment.

```
Double[] myArray = ...   // Of type Double[]
Set<Double> myset = new HashSet<Double>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Than convert it back to an array

```
double[] noDuplicates = myset.toArray(new double[myset.size()]);
```

The first step remove duplicates. The second step convert it back to an array.

---

If myArray is an array of double (primitive type) you need an additional step to convert it to the equivalent wrapper:

```
double[] myArrayOdPrimitives = ...
Double[] myArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(myArrayOdPrimitives);
Set<Double> myset = new HashSet<Double>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
double[] noDuplicates = myset.toArray(new double[myset.size()]);
```

Comment: `new HashSet<String>` is nor proper type for `Set<Double>`. Also `myset.toArray` is similar to `asList`. It also expects arrays of `T` type and `T` can't represent primitive type so `double[] noDuplicates = myset.toArray(new double[myset.size()]);` can't compile. Please test answer before posting it (this is not a race).

Comment: @Pshemo right... I started with a String. And I posted it. Then I saw that the questionnaire was asking for Double and I changed it without retesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a set from your array the set will excluse the duplicated items for you

## Example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double[] foo = { 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 };
    Set<Double> fSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(foo));
    System.out.println(fSet);
    }
```

this will print

> [3.1, 4.1, 1.1, 2.1]

wich is the desired output for you

Answer (score 0):

try this:
dont forget to use `Double` instead of `double` or `int` which are primitive types

```
 Double []signs = {83.4d,34.03d,4.301d,4.01d,34.03d,6.7d,4.01d,85d,83.4d};
        Set<Double> newSings = Stream.of(signs)
                              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

        System.out.println(newSings);
```

as method:

```
Double[] Duplicates(double[] signs) {

   Set<Double> signsfinal = Stream.of(signs)
                              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));;

   return signsfinal;
}
```

output:

> [4.01, 85.0, 4.301, 6.7, 83.4, 34.03]

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Set<double[]> myset = new HashSet<double[]>(Arrays.asList(signs));`, you actually create a `Set` of `double` arrays, where you actually want a set of `Double`. Try :

```
Double[] duplicates(double[] signs)
{
    Set<Double> myset = new HashSet<Double>();
    for (double d : signs)
    {
        myset.add(Double.valueOf(d));
    }
    Double[] signsfinal = (Double[]) myset.toArray();

    return signsfinal;
}
```

P.S: the convention in Java is to start the method names with a lowercase-character.

Comment: I tried it. I still get an error but it's a bit different ... it says: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Double[]
            at org.opencv.samples.tutorial1.LinesProcess.duplicates

Comment: @user3855955 That's weird, I don't get any errors with this code. But if it doesn't work for you, replace `Double[] signsfinal = (Double[]) myset.toArray();` with `Double[] signsfinal = myset.toArray(new Double[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 all you need is

```
double[] values = {1., 2., 1., 3.};
double[] uniques = DoubleStream.of(values).distinct().toArray();
```

Similar for `Double[]`

```
Double[] values = {1., 2., 1., 3.};
Double[] uniques = Stream.of(values).distinct().toArray(Double[]::new);
```